# How many strings of four decimal digits do not contain the same digit twice

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

The answer should be

1: Four different digits : $$10*9*8*7 = 5040 $$

2: Four different digits + contains the same digit three times + all digits are of the same : $$ 10*9*8*7+10*{4 \choose 3} *9 + 10 = 5410 $$

Which one is correct? Depend on different interpretation?

Comment: I think yes, it opens up to interpretation. Depending on what you interpreted, both answers are correct. I presume 0123 is also considered as a 4 decimal digit number

Comment: I would interpret the problem the first way since the strings $1332$, $3331$, and $3333$ contain the digit $3$ (at least) twice.

Comment: If a digit occurs thrice, it occurs twice too.

Comment: If the second way is what was intended, the question should be phrased as "... _exactly_ twice" in my opinion. Therefore I think the first way is correct.